# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError with tomcat and axis2

Tags: java, android, apache, tomcat

I am new to tomcat / axis2. already I installed and tested the tomcat alone and worked properly. But when I put tomcat and axis2 encounter this error. Can someone help me?

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>       at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>       at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
>       ... 31 more
>
> fev 17, 2016 6:59:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
>   SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet AxisServlet
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.ws.commons.schema.resolver.URIResolver
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1308)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1142)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ModuleDeployer.deploy(ModuleDeployer.java:128)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:144)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:585)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init(RepositoryListener.java:264)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.init2(RepositoryListener.java:66)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.(RepositoryListener.java:61)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadRepository(DeploymentEngine.java:152)
>       at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.getAxisConfiguration(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:233)
>       at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:64)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:620)
>       at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:471)
>       at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1151)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:828)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:135)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:522)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1095)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:672)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please pare that down a bit -- taking out the parts that worked, leaving the parts that didn't.

Comment: `Tomcat` does not know how to resolve the `org/apache/ws/commons/schema/resolver/URIResolver` class. You need to provide to `Tomcat`'s classpath the `jar` that contains the mentioned class. Usually one packs the dependency jars with the application. Or you could provide it directly to the server.

Answer (score 0):

When Tomcat doesn't found files on their proper place then java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: occured. To fix this problem make sure:

1. You have to set CATALINA_HOME & JAVA_HOME variables
2. Add your project html, jsp, css, images etc. files in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/your-project-directory
3. Add your java classes in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/your-project-directory/WEB-INF/classes
4. Place your java libraries in TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/your-project-directory/WEB-INF/lib
5. Make sure you written all classes in your web.xml (deployment descriptor)

Comment: I switched the version of eclipse (from mars to kepler) and used axis2 the version 1.6. It worked!  =)
thank you, guys!